# If $(x_n)$ has several limit, does $(x_n)$ converge in $E$ means that all it's limit are in $E$ or there is a limit in $E$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ a (non hausdorff) topological space. Let $E\subset X$. What mean $(x_n)\subset E$ converges in $E$ ? (i.e. a sequence of $E$ converges in $E$). Does it mean that

1) All it's limit are in $E$

or

2) Has at least one limit in $E$ ?

For example, if I take $X=\mathbb R$ and the coarse topology. Is for example $[0,1]$ sequentiel or not ? I know that a sequence in $[0,1]$ converge to every point, so it will also converge to $2\notin [0,1]$. So indeed a sequence of $[0,1]$ will converges in $[0,1]$, but it will also converges out of $[0,1]$. So does such a sequence converges in $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Regarding the notation $(x_n)\subset E$, I think it means the sequences are in $E$, i.e. $x_n\in E$ for all $n$.

Comment: @YuiToCheng: I know but it's not my question. I clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x_n)$ converges in $E$ means that there is at least one limit in $E$.

If $A=[0,1]$ in the indiscrete topology on $\Bbb R$, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $[0,1]$ then $0$ is a limit of $(x_n)$. But $A$ being sequentially closed means that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence from $A$ and $x_n \to x$ then $x \in A$, and that fails for $[0,1]$ (as $2$ is also a limit), so in the indiscrete topology only $X$ is sequentially closed (and $\emptyset$ too, trivially ). So the indiscrete topology is sequential in the sense that all sequentially closed sets are closed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The most natural interpretation should be:

> $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence of the topological space $(E,\tau_E)$.

Where $\tau_E=\{E\cap U\,:\, U\in\tau\}$. In other words, if and only there is some $x\in E$ such that, for all $U$ neighbourhoods of $x$, eventually $x_n\in U\cap E$. In the special case where $(x_n)$ is convergent (in $X$), this is tantamount to the sequence having at least one limit point in $E$.

The reason why this is more natural than the other is that it depends entirely on the topology of $E$ and on the sequence, whereas the second one depends heavily on a specific embedding $E\hookrightarrow X$. To clarify, we could consider ordinary $\Bbb R$ as a topological subset of $(\Bbb R\cup\{*\},\tau^*)$, where $$V\in\tau^*\iff (V\in\tau\land 0\notin V)\lor(\{*,0\}\subseteq V\land V\setminus \{*\}\in \tau)$$

If the definition were (1), for instance, then the sequence $(\frac1n)$ would cease to be "convergent in $\Bbb R$". This necessity of considering the ambient space rather than the sole subset, despite the seemingly "relative" nature of the statement, is the reason why interpretation (2) seems the most natural. Provided the author may give the definition he prefers.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence converges in $E$ if it has at least one limit in $E$. Think in the situation that you have a sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ in $E=(0,1]$ this sequence does not converge in $E$, but it does in $\{0\} \cup E$.